# How to show Java Method call on Object in HTML

Tags: java, html

im kinda new to all of this.

So i have a Java Objekt Car with a ArrayList of Wheels. Car has a method which retuns the milage of the 4 wheels. I want to print the summed milage on HTML.

The totale milage of all four wheels summs up to $milage

That was how i planed to show it on my html page, but i have no idea how to replace $milage with the java method call.
I am obv using thymleaf and Spring Boot (if that matters), but not JSP. Im on Java not JavaScript

I tried googeling my problem, but everyone is using JSP but i dont want to use that. (Or im just bad at googeling)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're using Thymleaf, then check out their docs. There's an easy solution possible in basic Java/Thymleaf.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Spring BOOT app, your Java code is executed on the backend and the view (thymleaf) only displays the data. You must define a controller and interact with the controller. For example, you can use a GET or POST to interact with the Spring BOOT controller. A GET or POST returns the data that is produced using Java and displayed in the page.

I suggest that you learn all the concepts of a Spring BOOT app by following some online tutorials to learn the basics.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/